# How to monitor docker UCP logs without console access?

Tags: docker, devops, docker-ucp

- once we have live logs in Ucp and if we have to check details for that log how can we do that?
- how to find out there are any issues from ucp logs?

Answer (score 0):

UCP logs can be viewed using a client bundle. This is an old blog entry, but UCP still works this way today:

[Get Familiar with Docker Enterprise Edition Client Bundles](https://www.docker.com/blog/get-familiar-docker-enterprise-edition-client-bundles/)

Comment: Since links can change and/or go down, it is beneficial to include the the essential parts of the answer here, so that your answer can remain relevant and not be at the mercy of another site.